# How to refer to gradle dependency source.jar

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, j2objc

I want to pass the dependency-x.y.z-sources.jar that gradle downloads as a parameter to another plugin (specifically j2objc )

Is there a way to have a reference to the downloaded source jar?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the gradle j2objc plugin? See [here](https://github.com/j2objc-contrib/j2objc-gradle/blob/master/dependencies.md#one-j2objc-project-plus-simple-external-libraries). In short, you need to make sure the gradle compile dependency you add specifies a specific version (no + or unspecified) and that the specified dependency provides a -sources.jar. After that, if you add `autoConfigureDeps true` to the top of your `j2objcConfig` closure it will pick up the sources.